# Please wait.. message in java itext pdf reader

Tags: java, itext

I am using java itext pdf reader to read data from pdf but when I run program I get following error

```
Please wait... 

If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF 
viewer may not be able to display this type of document. 

You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by 
visiting  http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download. 

    For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit  http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader. 

Windows is either a registered trademark or a trademark of Microsoft Corporation in the United States and/or other countries. Mac is a trademark 
of Apple Inc., registered in the United States and other countries. Linux is the registered trademark of Linus Torvalds in the U.S. and other 
countries.
```

Pdf contains form and tables. I am using ubutnu and adobe reader is updated.

Comment: AFAIK other readers then Adobe Reader have huge issues with interactive forms. And usually on failure there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the usual only regular content of a pdf with a XFA form. Thus, it is no error but all there is to extract via text extraction.

You can try to extract form data by means of the form related APIs of itext. The iText AcroForm APIs have a limited support for XFA data, and there also are methods for extracting the XFA xml.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. I can extract data in XML format.